# java.net.URI.relativize doesn't work with JAR URIs

Tags: java, uri

I have two URI objects. One is pointing to a folder in a JAR file, and another is pointing to a file in the same JAR file. The file is in a subfolder of the directory specified by the first URI. I like to create a relative URI so the resulting URI only containing the relative path to the file in the JAR.

- Folder URI

  ```
  jar:file:/C:/Users/inagy/.m2/repository/hu/inagy/my-config-artifact/2.0-SNAPSHOT/my-config-artifact-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/conf/
  ```
- Resource URI

  ```
  jar:file:/C:/Users/inagy/.m2/repository/hu/inagy/my-config-artifact/2.0-SNAPSHOT/my-config-artifact-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/conf/somesubpath/someconfig.xml
  ```
- After calling `folderUri.relativize(resourceURI)` i'm expecting the following URI as a result:

  ```
  somesubpath/someconfig.xml
  ```

However i get resourceURI back which mean according to the [URI class's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize%28java.net.URI%29) that the JDK code find this two paths non relative to each other.

Is this a bug or i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been mildly annoyed by this too. The answer has *nothing* do to with the semantics of JAR files—it has to do with the syntax of `jar:` URIs. To be "relativized," a URI has to be **hierarchical and not opaque**. You will note from the JavaDoc for java.net.URI that:

> At the highest level a URI reference (hereinafter simply "URI") in string form has the syntax
>
> ```
> [scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> An opaque URI is an absolute URI whose scheme-specific part does not begin with a slash character ('/'). Opaque URIs are not subject to further parsing.
>
> ...
>
> A hierarchical URI is subject to further parsing according to the syntax
>
> ```
> [scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]
> ```

A JAR URI like `jar:file:///home/me/foo.jar!/conf/` is parsed as:

- scheme = `jar`
- scheme-specific-part = `file:///home/me/foo.jar!/conf/`
- fragment = (none)

Because the scheme-specific-part does not begin with "`/`," it cannot be considered a hierarchical URI. The URI class does not treat `jar:` (or any) URIs specially, so it cannot recognize that the `file://` part is a nested URI that *is* hierarchical.

Since `jar:` URIs are opaque and not hierarchical, they are subject to the behavior documented for [URI#relativize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize%28java.net.URI%29):

> The relativization of the given URI against this URI is computed as
> follows:
>
> 1. If either this URI or the given URI are opaque, [...], then the given URI is returned.

**EDIT**: Left out a crucial part about opaque URIs.

Comment: URI.resolve() does also not understand the jar Scheme/Protocol. But URL(URL) does so.

Answer (score -1):

`somesubpath/someconfig.xml` is not an URI; the protocol (like `file:`) is missing. In fact only a full URL with `jar:file:/C:/Users/inagy/.m2/repository/hu/inagy/my-config-artifact/2.0-SNAPSHOT/my-config-artifact-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!somesubpath/someconfig.xml` would be imaginable, but the jar-protocol does not hande base documents/dirs, like `/conf`.

So you can only use absolute paths. A consequence of URI standing for Unique Resource Identifier.

There is no base document (.html) with relative documents (.js).

---

**An URI is to retrieve data.** How would one write a relative URI for a file inside a jar? Relative to where? As the "jar:" protocol is only used inside java code, there is no context of "current file". *So relative URIs are not implemented.*

Comment: I have used the same code with filesystem URIs (beginning with file:) and relativize returns that relative file path what i'm expecting as a relative URI. There's even an isAbsolute() function in the URI class to check against that.

Comment: @JoopEggen This is mistaken on almost every point. JAR URIs to directories inside the JAR file are certainly possible: ``getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("conf/")`` will return them if you have such a directory in your JAR. In any case, the semantics of JAR files are irrelevant, because syntax is all that the URI class cares about.

Comment: and ``somepath/somefile.xml`` *is* a URI. It's a relative hierarchical one. As for your "no base documents in JARs" theory: what about an HTML file inside a JAR file that has a relative URI for a link? There is no conceptual reason why you shouldn't be able to have a URI relative to a JAR URI. The problem here is the syntax.

Comment: @TimYates: having read your answer - which pleases me, just for its defining formality, I in my answer went for an **explanation/rationale** of `jar:` not having a state (base document). My answer is: normal jar handling has no *current base*. I would say that a java programmed web browser could relativize principally, you say not because of a missing (=illegal) `jar://` + `/`. You are technically correct, and you get my upvote.