# Exception when run builded jar : JavaFX

Tags: exception, javafx, jar, resourcebundle, artifact

The program runs from idea and works correctly, but when i build it and make run error appears. I will paint the line because of which the exception throws.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ../bundles/locale, locale ru
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at base.Main.start(Main.java:21)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application base.Main
```

P.S. sorry for English

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error helps

Comment: not helped ((((

Comment: It can't find a resource -> Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ../bundles/locale, locale ru

Comment: As stated in the answer to the question I linked, `..` is not a valid resource name, so this won't work in a jar file...

Comment: But which is a valid resource name in a jar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Intellij Idea and this problem was solved